# Смена цвета css элемента в jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

```js
/*При вызове функции "A" нужно через **JQuery** к элементам класса "a" в блоке на который клинули, покрасить в красный цвет.

Не знаю как правильно написать селектор..

Что то примерно этого: 
*/


function A(t) {

}


function A(t) {
  $(t + " .a").css("color", "red"); // Но это не работает.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onClick="A(this)">
  <a href="..." class="a">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div onClick="A(this)">
  <a href="..." class="a">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div onClick="A(this)">
  <a href="..." class="a">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: не делайте onclick в разметке.

Comment: @dfgdfgdfg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.a').click(function(e){
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: мне показалось, что надо

    $(this).parent().find('a');

Comment: @eicto, если так, то просто $(this)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.a').click(function(){
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="a">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="a">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="a">Link 3</a>
</div>
```